# SingleChildScrollView now working inside Column

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I was to layout a page that has a side menu and a top menu that don't move. I wanted the rest of the page to be scrollable. I have wrapped my column in a singlechildscrollview but nothing happens. I still get an overflow error and cannot scroll. Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const SideMenu(),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 75.0,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: const [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'data',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                          child: Text('data'),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'data',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: const [
                        Text(
                          'Test Text',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 155.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Test Text',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 155.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: [This](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html) might help.

Answer (score 2):

you have to know behaviour of `SingleChildScrollView`

try this

```
Row(
 children:[
  SideMenu(),
  Expanded(
   child: Column(
     children:[ 
       Container(),
       Expanded(  // add this.
         child: SingleChildScrollView(),
....
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your **Expanded** widget with a **SingleChildScrollView** instead of just the Column. Here's the code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const SideMenu(),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 75.0,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      children: const [
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'data',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                          child: Text('data'),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'data',
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: const [
                          Text(
                            'Test Text',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 155.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Test Text',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 155.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```